# Finding $a_n$ using a given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to find a formula for $a_n$, where:

> $a_0 = a,$
>   $a_1=b,$
>   $a_{n+2}=6a_{n+1}-9a_n$

By looking at $a_2, a_3, a_4$... I did manage to see some formula, but I don't think this is the right way.

Instead, in an earlier question, I'm asked to find the Jordan form of

$$ A=\begin{pmatrix}
6 & -9 \\ 
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

I found it to be

$$G=\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 1 \\ 
0 & 3
\end{pmatrix}$$

Also, $G^n=3^{n-1}\begin{pmatrix}
3 & n \\ 
0 & 3
\end{pmatrix}$

Now, I noticed that if $v=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{n+1}\\ 
a_n
\end{pmatrix}$, then $Av=\begin{pmatrix}
6a_{n+1}-9a_n\\ 
a_{n+1}
\end{pmatrix}$ and for our sequence,

we need $$Av=\begin{pmatrix}
6a_{n+1}-9a_n\\ 
a_{n+1}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{n+2}\\ 
a_{n+1}
\end{pmatrix}$$

But from here on I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: We have $A^n\begin{pmatrix} a_1\\a_0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a_{n+1}\\a_n\end{pmatrix}$, hence you only have to compute $A^n$. It won't be difficult since you have computed $G^n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that there's much left to do for you. If you use the fact that $A = SGS^{-1}$, where

$$S = \begin{pmatrix}3&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$$

then you can simply calculate
$$A^n v = (SGS^{-1})^n v = SG^nS^{-1}v$$
using the expression for $G^n$ that you obtained above and you should have your final result by reading off the entries of $A^n v$.

Regards,
Jan

Comment: It's possible OP found the Jordan form without ever finding the matrix $S$. If so, that could be what OP was missing.

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting to solve is a linear recurrence relation.  Check out the book [Concrete Mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201558025).  These are explicitly solvable.

Comment: Yes, but OP is trying to solve it *by a particular method*, namely, by building on the earlier problem.